# Audio not playing from Python script from server

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, web, server

I am facing a peculiar issue here.  I am trying to load all the audio links to my Python script from a json file so that they can be played client side, they display correctly but after the 4th nothing plays - I press the play button but there is no audio.

I have the path of several sound files stored in a json file (what I am trying to load is much bigger ~50-60 urls) but here is an example:

file.json:

```
{

    "Music Type 1" : "http://music/file1.mp3",
    "Music Type 2" : "http://music/file2.mp3",
    "Music Type 3" : "http://music/file3.mp3",
    "Music Type 4" : "http://music/file4.mp3",
    "Music Type 5" : "http://music/file5.mp3"
}
```

And to display these on my webpage I am using the following:

```
#!C:/Network/Python/Scripts/python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")

import json
a = json.load(open('file.json'))

for i in a.keys():
    print('<h1>{}</h1>\n'.format(i))
    print('<audio controls><source src="{}"></audio>'.format(a[i]))
```

Everything displays correctly when viewing source (browser side):

```
<h1>Music Type 1</h1>

<audio controls><source src="http://music/file1.mp3"></audio>
<h1>Music Type 2</h1>

<audio controls><source src="http://music/file2.mp3"></audio>
<h1>Music Type 3</h1>

<audio controls><source src="http://music/file3.mp3"></audio>
<h1>Music Type 4</h1>

<audio controls><source src="http://music/file4.mp3"></audio>
<h1>Music Type 5</h1>

<audio controls><source src="http://music/file5.mp3"></audio>
```

My first thoughts that the urls were wrong, so I checked the url of `Music Type 5` and it was correct.  It played from browser as expected.

I then tried a second Python script with the same url and it played perfectly:

```
#!C:/Network/Python/Scripts/python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")

print('<audio controls><source src="http://music/file5.mp3"></audio>')
```

For those who do not know how to use the audio tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) is a quick reference.  I am running XAMPP server Windows.  The files are also live streams.

I do not understand why the audio is not playing.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this, or what could be causing this problem?

Comment: out of curiosity, what does 'print(repr(a[i]))` yield for you? Wondering if one of the `/` is being escaped.

Comment: @MooingRawr  It returns this: `'http://music/file1.mp3'
'http://music/file2.mp3'
'http://music/file3.mp3'
'http://music/file4.mp3'
'http://music/file5.mp3'`  Just let me check my original.  It might be that.

Comment: @MooingRawr  The output of the json file is printing correctly browser side.  If I view source, and select one of the links it plays.  It is a live stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the mp3 files were corrupt, the browser did not recognise them to play.  The script itself works fine.